# Set title to implemented UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My code:

```
@interface BIDMyClass ()

@end

@implementation BIDMyClass {
    UINavigationBar *settingsBar;
}

-(void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    settingsBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [settingsBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 293.0f, 44.0f)];
    [settingsBar.topItem setTitle:@"Settings"];
    [self.view addSubview:settingsBar];
}
```

`settingsBar` is added but there is no title on it. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is your view controller inside of a UINavigationController?

Comment: yes. but it must be independent UINavigationBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`settingsBar.topItem` is probably nil. Try setting the list of items on your `settingsBar`:

```
settingsBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings"] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you may also declare your:

```
    IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
```

and connect in IB. Assuming you have an XIB file with the navBar on it.